# display wordpress sub menu items only for a given menu item

Tags: wordpress

I’m having some trouble with creating a very custom menu in WordPress.

Basically, I need to get a list of all SUB menu items for a specific menu item, for example

Menu structure

```
item 1 (link)   <--- level 1
  leftside  <--- level 2
    subitem a (link)  <--- level 3
    subitem b (link)  <--- level 3
    subitem c (link)  <--- level 3
    subitem d (link)  <--- level 3
    ...

  rightside  <--- level 2
    subitem a (link) <--- level 3
    subitem b (link) <--- level 3
    subitem c (link) <--- level 3
    subitem d (link) <--- level 3
    ...
```

I want to write a function where I can ask for:
 1. all the submenu items for a level 1 item and it will give me the level 2 items under it
 2. all the submenu items for a level 2 item and it will give me the level 3 items under it

Answer (score 0):

You could determine this manually by looking at the source code output of the site. For example, menus start with  tags and menu items use

tags, with the "id" defined being the list of the specific menu items.

For example, on one of my sites, we have an admin bar menu for BP:

```
    <ul class="ab-sub-secondary ab-submenu" id="wp-admin-bar-my-account-wordpress">
     <li id="wp-admin-bar-my-account-notifications" class="menupop">Notifications</li>
    ...
    </ul>
```

In this case, the sub-items all start with the id:

wp-admin-bar-

And this particular one is wp-admin-bar-my-account-notifications.

You could for example, remove this, with something like:

```
     function remove_nodes() {
      $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('my-account-notifications');
     }
     add_action('admin_bar_menu','remove_nodes', 2);
```